# Download a file using Invoke -WebRequest in Powershell by calling a .ps1 file using a batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to do something like ,
I have to download some file using powershell Invoke -WebRequest cmdlet which I have scripted in a "myscript.ps1" file in my hardrive
Now I wish to call and execute this file in Powershell using cmd by creating a batch file for calling a powershell file in Powershell 
How do I do it??

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be rude but did you look this up at all?  Or search Stackoverflow for similar questions first?  It seems that all you are asking is how to run a PowerShell script.  I googled this and got several very well written guides on the subject.

1. Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Depending on the environment this may not be what you want to do, since you are basically turning off the security against unauthorized scripts.

2. Powershell.exe -File "myscript.ps1"

http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-powershell-scripts-easy-1-2-3

Comment: just needed your help in regarding this that I first made a batch file to run powershell using the command: PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""D:\myscript.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}" then made a .ps1 file and wrote Invoke -WebRequest command to download some file still when ever I run Powershell this doesn't executes...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to download a file there is no need to use a .ps1 file.
For example to download the MAC address Vendorlist I use this in a batch:

```
powershell -nop -command "iwr \"http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt\" -Outfile \"%temp%\oui.txt\""
```

I won't permanently change the `ExecutionPolicy` to `unrestricted`, either use `RemoteSigned` or include  `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` in the above command.

Comment: See I made a batch file like:

Comment: I went up with you code to download a jpeg file from google into the d drive on my machine. But It showed the error saying **Invoke -Web Request A positional parameter cannot be found  that accepts the argument <path_of_my_directory_where_i _wish_to_download>**

Comment: Double quotes enclose the whole command, any other double quotes inside these have to be escaped with a backslash `\"`.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, keep an elevated PowerShell window open to see all output streams (warnings and errors in particular).

To do that, use either `-NoExit` parameter

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoExit -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""D:\myscript.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

or `pause` function as `-Command ""D:\myscript.ps1;pause""` instead of `-File ""D:\myscript.ps1""`

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ""D:\myscript.ps1;pause""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

Note that any of above methods would not help if `D:\myscript.ps1` file does not exist. Moreover, I'm not sure about `pause` method effectivity in case of a terminating error in invoked script.

Comment: In your code I couldn't find as to where to insert the **download link** also **pause works** and as I ran the program the Powershell throwed Error like _**The Term Invoke is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet**_

Comment: Sorry. At Stack Overflow, we are not a script writing service. As per your question, you have scripted it already: _… `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet which **I have scripted** in a `"myscript.ps1"` file_. However, note that you have a harmful space between `Invoke` and `-WebRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to start Powershell as a separate process. Just execute the script with & pathToScript.ps1. Here is an example of downloading a Powershell script and running it:

```
$chocoInstallScriptUrl  = 'http://.../install/Install.Choco.ps1'
$chocoInstallScript     = Join-Path $env:Temp 'Install.Choco.ps1'

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

$downloader = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$downloader.DownloadFile($chocoInstallScriptUrl, $chocoInstallScript)

& $chocoInstallScript
```